# Android TextView, lineSpacingExtra + backgroundColor issue

Tags: android, spannablestring

I am using TextView with SpannableString to change the background color of some word like the picture below but there's a problem with attr 'lineSpacingExtra'. As you can see the pic, some bottom-padding added when using 'lineSpacingExtra'. I wonder how to fit this padding to the height of text.

here's my code snippet.

in .kt

```
spannableString.setSpan(BackgroundColorSpan({color}), 0, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

[image]

in .xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"/>
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Remove `android:lineSpacingExtra` attribute.

Comment: but I should add some spacing between lines.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want _line spacing_ = _text height_?

Comment: I want to get rid of the bottom margin of the text background but also remain spacing between lines.